# SQL - replace constant with variable

Tags: sql, oracle, variables

How to replace the constant 'constantHere' with a variable? I use plain SQL, I understand that concept of variables doesn't exist in plain SQL but maybe there is a workaround?

It is important that I left '%' sign there, as I never know how the constant ends.

I have multiple unions and the same 'constantHere' as a condition. Each time I run the script I need to change it. I'd like to have only 1 place in the code to change it instead of scrolling up and down and change all of them.

```
select tuse.user_id             user_id,
        tuse.user_name          user_name,
        tuse.login_name         login,
        tuse.is_active          user_active,
        userint.role_code       role_code,
        userint.is_active       role_active,
        null     special_priv,
        null      special_priv_active
        
from object.t_user                                                        tuse
    left join object.user_special_privilege                                 usespec
        on tuse.user_id = usespec.user_id
    left join object.special_privilege                                      specpriv
        on usespec.special_privilege_id = specpriv.special_privilege_id
    left join object.user_role_int                                          userint
        on tuse.user_id = userint.user_id

where upper(tuse.user_name) like upper('constantHere%')

union

select tuse.user_id             user_id,
        tuse.user_name          user_name,
        tuse.login_name         login,
        tuse.is_active          user_active,
        null      role_code,
        null       role_active,
        specpriv.description    special_priv,
        specpriv.is_active      special_priv_active
        
from object.t_user                                                        tuse
    left join object.user_special_privilege                                 usespec
        on tuse.user_id = usespec.user_id
    left join object.special_privilege                                      specpriv
        on usespec.special_privilege_id = specpriv.special_privilege_id
    left join object.user_role_int                                          userint
        on tuse.user_id = userint.user_id

where upper(tuse.user_name) like upper('constantHere%')

order by 2, 5, 7
```

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Comment: The tag rmdbs is too vargue

Comment: Probably the only way to do this is to embed your SQL in a Function - but as that is likely to be specific to the RDBMS you are using you need to tag your question with the correct RDBMS. Also, it would be helpful if you updated your question to explain what you are trying to achieve - at a higher level than just replacing a constant with a variable. If we know what you are trying to do we can suggest solutions that may achieve what you want, and not suggested solutions that won't work for you

Comment: @NickW tried that tag before but got removed. I added more info to the original post.

Comment: Are you looking for bind variables? `like upper(:my_constant || '%')`?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner most likely but I can't implement it properly in this code... I don't know how to declare variable. Where is the proper place? Before 1st Select?

Comment: You don't declare it. You just run the query and your tool (SQL Developer) will ask you for the value.

Comment: Can I have it predefined before I run the code?

Comment: Well, it kind of is. You run the code, but nothing happens yet, then you enter the value, and the query gets executed. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quote:  " *I'd like to have only 1 place in the code to change it instead of scrolling up and down and change all of them*."   ...end quote.

If this is what you need then you could place it in CTE:

```
WITH var_def AS (Select 'something' "constantHere" From Dual)   -- define it here
select tuse.user_id             user_id,
        tuse.user_name          user_name,
        tuse.login_name         login,
        tuse.is_active          user_active,
        userint.role_code       role_code,
        userint.is_active       role_active,
        null     special_priv,
        null      special_priv_active
        
from object.t_user
    Inner Join var_def ON(1 = 1)       --  here you attach var_def.constantHere to every row                                                        tuse
    left join object.user_special_privilege                                 usespec
        on tuse.user_id = usespec.user_id
    left join object.special_privilege                                      specpriv
        on usespec.special_privilege_id = specpriv.special_privilege_id
    left join object.user_role_int                                          userint
        on tuse.user_id = userint.user_id

where upper(tuse.user_name) like upper(var_def.constantHere||'%')   -- here you use it

union

select tuse.user_id             user_id,
        tuse.user_name          user_name,
        tuse.login_name         login,
        tuse.is_active          user_active,
        null      role_code,
        null       role_active,
        specpriv.description    special_priv,
        specpriv.is_active      special_priv_active
        
from object.t_user   
Inner Join var_def ON(1 = 1)       --  here you attach var_def.constantHere to every row                                              tuse
    left join object.user_special_privilege                                 usespec
        on tuse.user_id = usespec.user_id
    left join object.special_privilege                                      specpriv
        on usespec.special_privilege_id = specpriv.special_privilege_id
    left join object.user_role_int                                          userint
        on tuse.user_id = userint.user_id

where upper(tuse.user_name) like upper(var_def.constantHere||'%')   -- here you use it

order by 2, 5, 7
```

Now you have only 1 place to change it ....  Name your constant accordingly and with capital letters. I put the name constantHere because you used it in question.

Comment: For 12c and above CTE may be replaced with inline function declaration with `pragma udf;` and `deterministic`, which may be little shorter that subquery

Comment: Sorry d r, what are 'something' and "constantHere" in the very first select? I can't get this code to run.

Comment: @DonAndress 'something' is string that you compare your table column with. That is  the string you want to change for every run. As stated in the answer constantHere is column name that you should  name as you wish and it doesn't change. It could be like "ACTUAL_USER_NAME" or anything else that suits you.

Comment: I get error in the first line like this: where upper(tuse.user_name) like upper(var_def.constantHere||'%')  and it's on (var_def

Comment: @DonAndress Either put var_def. "constantHere"  enclosed with double quotes in Where clause or, better, name the cte column in WITH  Clause to be like "ACTUAL_USER" and in Where use it as var_def.ACTUAL_USER

Comment: Yes, this worked but why? Why ACTUAL_USER is better than constantHere?

Comment: @DonAndress Oracle defaults object names as all uppercase. You can do it in any other way but then you should enclose it within double quotes

Answer (score 0):

Use Substitution variable.

use define constantHere='SomeValue'

Replace with &&constantHere

Comment: This solution would be specific to the client technology used.